# ASUS DSL-N16 Router Localhost Connection Issue

Tags: router, localhost, timeout

I started using ASUS DSL-N16 model router recently. When I send consecutive requests to the stand-alone PHP web server that I run on "127.0.0.1:88" I receive a "server time out" error after 20-25 requests.

I took a look at the settings in the admin panel, but the details are too complicated for me. I just tried disabling the firewall (not sure if this is okay to do) and the problem did not resolve.

I have never experienced this problem with different brands and models of routers I have used before.

*Addition: QoS enabled/disabled modes were also tried.*

Comment: Seems like your PHP server dies out after those 20-25 requests. You should debug why.

Comment: @harrymc I don't think so because I'm still using exact same infrastructure and code. I just changed the router and was able to run everything without a problem with previous routers.

Comment: In that case it seems that the router is blocked. Is it possible that you're not closing the connections ?

Comment: @harrymc I installed the router with quick setup guide and didn't touch anything. I don't even know how to close connections. I'm suspecting that some default security settings automatically blocking repetitive requests for protection.

Comment: Unlikely that the router contains such a setting. How are you executing the requests on the server - via browser, JavaScript, or what?

Comment: @harrymc Thank you for your time and interest. I'm running a PHP web app which makes ajax requests to localhost for dynamic content and at the back-end there are other API connections happening to other servers around the world. I've tested the API URLs when I get "server time out" error and they're working & reachable, so I think something happening at the localhost requests level.

Comment: There are too many variables flying around. You'll need to investigate in order to get a handle on the problem. The router might have some logging facility or otherwise find what error the last request is getting. Add all the details to your post, including what's in the comments, for the benefit of other readers.